# Navigation bar not appearing when using bootstrap CDN for Django

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, cdn

I'm following a tutorial to make websites with Django. I'm currently trying to add a navigation bar using bootstrap CDN but the following appears. The code I am using is posted below.

There is no navigation bar present:

[image: 1]

Below is the code is used.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
        initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81i\
        uXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
                
        <title>{% block title %}Newspaper App{% endblock title %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Newspaper</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ user.username }}
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"
                                aria-labelledby="userMenu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item"
                                href="{% url 'password_change'%}">Change password</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">
                                Log Out</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                {% else %}
                    <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
                        <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                        Log In</a>
                        <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">
                        Sign up</a>
                    </form>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock content %}
        </div>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4\
        YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/\
        1.14.3/
        umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbB\
        JiSnjAK/
        l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/\
        js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ\
        6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The site is supposed to display a navigation bar with the users name at the top right.

Answer (score 0):

to use CDN you need active internet connection, here looks like either you are developing offline or your django project does not have access to internet.

if developing offline is your requirement, then you may download those CDN files, then use them.